# Is collision possible in a star topology switch link layer ?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

I am learning about collision detection in ethernet protocols. Since each host has its own channel to forward to the switch, is it possible for collision to happen if the switch receives two frames at the same time ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If we are talking about a *switch*, it isn't a shared medium where collision can occur.**

The ***switch*** switches connections to let packets through. A packet comes in from Port 1 and wants to go to port 2.  A second packet comes in on port 3 and wants to go to port 2 as well. The switch first connects Ports 1&2 letting the packet through disconnects and then connects ports 2&3 letting the 2nd packet go through.

```
This was an overly simplified example.
```

Comment: could you elaborate further on the connecting and disconnecting part ? does that mean that if 2 frames arrive at the switch, both destined for the same port, then the switch will buffer one frame while letting the other frame transmit to that port. And this only applies to frames that are forwarded to the same port ?

Comment: That depends on the switch, see http://etutorials.org/Networking/lan+switching/Chapter+6.+How+a+Switch+Works/Layer+2+Switching+Methods/

Comment: @calveen I don't know as much, but to reinforce Tarnay's comment, it does depends on the hardware of the switch.